# find the number of rows based on column mapping in sql

Tags: sql

i am completely new to sql.I am trying to learn things in sql. Juts stuck upon something.  Say i have a table with two colmumns customername  and customer address. multiple customers can be mapped to the same address. How can retrieve the address with maximum customers ?

[image]

Comment: what database are you using? sounds like a requirement too great for plain SQL

Comment: i am using mysql.. Here next row might have ram as customer_name and trichur as the customer_addres. So i want the address with maxim customer_names mapped to it, is my question clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using grouping (to get the counts), ordering (descending) and limiting (to get the top row). In MySQL for instance, it might look like this:

```
SELECT customer_address, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS number_of_customers 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY customer_address 
ORDER BY number_of_customers DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

This will yield something like:

```
+------------------+---------------------+
| customer_address | number_of_customers |
+------------------+---------------------+
|              foo |                  42 |
+------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: thanksa lot alexnader, a small edit , we have to give asc instead desc.

Comment: can we use a max funcction ?